# ldap get defined enums and their values from schema

Tags: enums, active-directory, attributes, ldap, schema

is there any way to get enum attributes and their possible values from LDAP schema?
if not what is the best source to get that?

I am specifically looking for a way to get all possible enum attributes and their allowable values that pre-defined in LDAP schema.

Answer (score 1):

You can query the schema for all attributes that use the [Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/s-enumeration) type using this query:

```
 (&(objectClass=attributeSchema)(attributeSyntax=2.5.5.9))
```

But based on your last question, I'm guessing you were hoping for more than that. But that's really all the schema will tell you. In general, the schema doesn't tell you the logic that AD uses to enforce the values of any attribute.

For the allowed values, you will have to look up documentation for each attribute. For example, the [documentation for `userAccountControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-useraccountcontrol) shows you all the values. But even that is a bit flag value, meaning that any of those values can be added together.

Some enumeration attributes don't have any enforcement at all. I can set the [`flags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-flags) attribute to any number I want and it lets me.